# Should an AppDomain have short or long life?

Tags: c#, appdomain

I'm working on an application extension system (plugins) where each plugin should be isolated into a separate `AppDomain`. The work is about to be completed, but there is still one important question about how long an `AppDomain` should live.

The system is used server-side, and it uses the plugins regularly, let's say it should call each plugin in every ten minutes once. In this case, taking every kind of overhead of `AppDomain`s into count, which is more appropriate?

1. Create the `AppDomain` instances once and keep them alive for the entire life-cycle of the application (so each plugin call will go into the same `AppDomain` per plugin).
2. Create the `Appdomain` instances for each plugin calls and then `Unload` them.

Comment: Consider that the default `AppDomain` lives for the entire lifetime of your program, so it's not unreasonable to keep it around for as long as you need it.

Comment: @Alejandro thanks for the comment, yeah that's a valid point. However I'm not sure what amount of memory and other kind of overhead an `AppDomain` has, and I could not find any documentation or article on this topic yet, that's why I'm not sure.

Comment: I do realize that this is not a great question, I'll still keep this open because hopefully someone can share some experience on this. In the meantime I'll do some performance testing.

Answer (score 1):

Using `AppDomain.CreateDomain(...)`:

1). create new app domain for each plugin and keep it alive during the entire application lifetime

- pros: no overhead for: creating app domain, loading .dlls, etc on each plugin call
- cons: all .dlls from all app domains are eating the memory during the entire application lifetime; need to be careful with static variables; no sandboxing between calls (if one breaks the app domain then all calls will fail)

2). create new app domain for each plugin call and unload after

- pros: sandboxing between calls; releasing memory between calls
- cons: overhead for: creating app domain, loading .dlls, etc on each plugin call

If you have many calls per plugin and large batch of .dlls for it, use option 1

If you have many calls per plugin and small batch of .dlls for it, use option 2

If you have few calls per plugin and small batch of .dlls for it, use option 2

If you want sandboxing between calls, use option 2